# MsAccess Sum of Column in Query to Textbox

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a Query that gives me just the Sum of all pieces from a different query. So there is only 1 value in this table besides column name (SumOfQty_FRL). I am trying to get this value, on load, as a control source for a form. I have tried DLookup, DCount, and DSum. I am not sure if am doing this correctly.

```
Me.txt_TotQty = DLookup("[SumOfQty_FRL]", "[qryTotalQty]")
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake, but nothing shows up in the textbox. Thanks for you help.

Comment: The expression looks okay. Why use VBA? Could have the DLookup in ControlSource property. Does qryTotalQty have any filter criteria? Why not just do DSum on the different query?

Comment: When you open qryTotalQty raw, does it return anything?